# Time based calculation in Java

Tags: java, time

I am creating a program that makes a calculation every minute. I don't know exactly how to do this efficiently, but this is some pseudo code I have written so far:

```
 stockCalcTimerH = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1;
    stockCalcTimerI = stockCalcTimerH;
    stockCalcTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (stockCalcTimerI < stockCalcTimer) {
      *do calcuations*
     stockCalcTimerI + 60000;
```

When I print both values out on the screen, it comes out as this:

stockCalcTimerI = 1395951070595
stockCalcTimer = 1395951010596

It only subtracts the number, and doesn't add the 60000 milliseconds...
I'm kind of new to Java, but any feedback helps.

Thanks for reading!!

Comment: I lied it worked in the first place...

Comment: What do you mean by `stockCalcTimerI + 60000;` ? If you mean `stockCalcTimerI += 60000;` then ok never adds 60000 milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

```
stockCalcTimerI + 60000;
```

The new value never gets assigned to a variable.

Change that to:

```
stockCalcTimerI += 60000;
```

Which is the same as

```
stockCalcTimerI = stockCalcTimerI + 60000;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`java.util.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class to schedule runs.

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override public void run() {
        // do calculations
    }
};
int delay = 0;          // no delay, execute immediately
int interval = 60*1000; // every minute
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(task, delay, interval);
```